# How to extract spaces from char array string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

The function of program is to verify if string is a palindrome while extracting punctuation. The code extracts double quotes and single quotes but I cant seem to figure out how to extract spaces. When watching array value with spaces from debugger it seems as if the string is being truncated where the spaces were inserted. I input ra da r from keyboard and the array value of string is ra in debugger watch list.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

bool palindrome(char[], int);

int main()
{
using namespace std;
bool status;
int siz,i;
char strarry[20];
siz = 0;

cout << " enter string" << endl;
cin >> strarry;

for (i = 0; strarry[i] != '\0'; i++)
    ++siz;

status = palindrome(strarry, siz);
if (status)
    cout << " the string is a palindrome" << endl;
else
    cout << "not a palindrome" << endl;

cin.clear();
cin.ignore(255, '/n');
cin.get();


return 0;
}

bool palindrome(char arry[], int size)
{
int i, l;
char arryn, arrysize;
static bool search = false;
static bool match = false;
static bool found = false;
static int n = 0;
int end = size - 1;

if (search != true){
    for (i = 0; i <= end; i++){
    if ((arry[i] == ' ') || (arry[i] == '\'') || (arry[i] == '\"')){
            if ((end - i) >= 1){
                for (l = i; l <= end; l++)
                    arry[l] = arry[l + 1];
                --end;
                size = end;
            }
            else{
                size= end - 1;
            }
            found = true;
    }//end if
    }// end for
    if (found == false)
        size = end;
    search = true;
}//end if



if (((n - size) <= 1) && match )
    return true;
else{
    arryn = arry[n];
    arrysize = arry[size];
    if (arry[n] == arry[size]){
        ++n;
        match = true;
        return palindrome(arry, size - 1);
    }
    else{
        match = false;
        return false;
    }//end else

}// end else


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with your code is that you are using:

```
cin >> strarry;
```

**cin** considers white-space, tabs, new-lines etc to be terminating characters, and therefore it will stop reading the remainder of the line once it encounters one of these characters.

The solution is to to use:

```
getline(cin, strarry);
```

This restricts the delimiter to new-line characters.

Answer (score 0):

point one; use strings. this is c++, ditch c-style strings

point two; use `getline`. when you do `cin >> strarry` it will only read up to first whitespace. fix this by using `getline(cin,str)`

point three; trim whitespace first. the is-a-palindrome function will be *way* simpler to write if you first construct a new string without whitespce. you can do that with the erase-remove idiom, and `isspace`